# Maps not running in android application

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I need the Android maps v2 api key..

but I am only getting android key and not the android maps key v2.

where so I get those? Please give me detailed steps is possible.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtain_a_google_maps_api_key

Comment: http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435